# Strange compile error in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Why does the type of `max prod nextProd` get inferred as `Int->Int->Int` instead of just Int in the below function?

```
import qualified Data.Vector as DV

largestProduct::DV.Vector Int->(Int, Int)
largestProduct digits = foldl lastProdAndMax (0,0) [1..((DV.length digits) - 13)] where
    lastProdAndMax _ 1 = (first, first) where first = DV.foldl (*) 1 $ DV.take 13 digits
    lastProdAndMax (prod, max) i = (nextProd, max prod nextProd)
        where nextProd = (prod `div` ((DV.!) digits (i-13))) * ((DV.!) digits i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in

```
lastProdAndMax (prod, max) i = (nextProd, max prod nextProd) 
                      ^^^
```

in that scope, `max` is a `Int` (overloading the `max` function).

Comment: @Julio Using the `-Wall` GHC flag would have triggered a warning for the shadowing of the global `max`, pointing to the problem.